# Run java class file from cron in openshift

Tags: java, cron

I am running a `cron` job to a task in `openshift`, here is my script

```
ROOT_DIR='$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'

if [ $(($minute % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
    java OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIRsrc.main.java.com.fs.sstore.communicator.scheduler.RechargeScheduler
fi
```

following error occurs on `server.log`:

> Could not find or load class.

I am trying to run single java file.

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: First, `ROOT_DIR` variable contains exactly `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR`, not its value. Replace single quotes for double quotes to get its value. I.e, `ROOT_DIR="$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"`. Which class is not loaded? Have you tried running from command line, instead of script? Does it run?

Comment: its running from command line. I need to make it run from script, my modified script now

Comment: I meant, if you run from command line: `java "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"/src.main.java.com.fs.sstore.communicator.scheduler.RechargeScheduler`, does it work or you get same error? Which error and which class is not able to load? Is it `RechargeScheduler`?

Comment: yes RechargeScheduler, i tried what u suggested, yeah its not loading class file from there.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you probably need to specify its `CLASSPATH`. using `-cp`. Try this from command line:

```
java -cp "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR" src.main.java.com.fs.sstore.communicator.scheduler.Recharg‌​eScheduler
```

Or go to base location where classes are (I guess `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR`), and run again:

```
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
java -cp . src.main.java.com.fs.sstore.communicator.scheduler.Recharg‌​eScheduler
```

By the way, make sure, package for `Recharg‌​eScheduler` is `src.main.java.com.fs.sstore.communicator.scheduler`. 
It's odd that it starts by `src`. It usually means its source location, but it's not part of package.

**==== UPDATE ====**

Let's make an easy example. Imagine a class like this, whose `StackOverflow.java` file is located in `/home/user/workspace/XTest/src/test/StackOverflow.java`:

Note that, in this case, package is `test` and **NOT** `src.test`

```
package test;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

There are several ways to  run this class from command line:

1. **Using Jar with no `Main-Class`entry**:

   Create JAR:

   ```
   cd /home/user/workspace/XTest/src //if its .class is in ./test/StackOverflow.class
   jar cvf /home/user/jar/stackOverflow.jar test/StackOverflow.class
   ```

   Once jar is generated, it can be run:

   ```
   cd /home/user/jar
   java -cp stackOverflow.jar test.StackOverflow
   ```
2. **Using Jar with `Main-Class`entry**:

   Create MANIFEST.MF file with an entry like this:

   ```
   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Main-Class: test.StackOverflow
   ```

   Then create JAR:

   ```
   cd /home/user/workspace/XTest/src //if its .class is in ./test/StackOverflow.class
   jar cvfm /home/user/jar/stackOverflow.jar MANIFEST.MF test/StackOverflow.class
   ```

   To run:

   ```
   cd /home/user/jar
   java -jar stackOverflow.jar
   ```
3. **Without using jar**

   Go where `test` package is located, and under its contents is compiled class

   ```
   cd /home/user/workspace/XTest/src
   ```

   If you list the contents here you should see something like:

   ```
   -rw-r--r-- 1 User group 5123 Mar 3 11:01 test/StackOverflow.class
   ```

   To run:

   ```
   java -cp . test.StackOverflow
   ```

Now, you can run these examples from any other location. 
For example in case 3, it can be run:

```
java -cp /home/user/workspace/XTest/src/. test.StackOverflow
```

Or in case 2:

```
java -jar /home/user/jar/stackOverflow.jar
```

Hope you can adapt this example to yours.

Comment: still show error, but found a way through in script to reach the target file

Comment: If you can, you should post the solution you found. It may help other people ;)

Comment: i've also get the same error how to solve it ? @java.1.

Comment: @fawwaz make runnable jar and run using this script          
java -cp *:.: com.your.package.location.ClassName

Comment: i still doesn't understand what should i do ? i've create a *.jar and i put it on src/main/java/com/mypackage/MyJar.jar what command should i call ? @java.1.

Comment: Well, it depends how you created jar file. If your `MANIFEST.MF` file in jar, contains a [`Main-Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) entry, then you can run it by: `java -jar <file.jar>`. If it does not `java -cp <jar_location> Main_Class`, where `Main_Class` contains the whole package, as @java.1. told.

Comment: @fawwaz, I updated my answer with a simple example. I hope it make things clear.